Why does the colon display lower than all of the other characters in Text ending in colon in SwiftUI?
I recently started using SwiftUI. Today, I've come across the oddest phenomenon. When I display simple Text ending in a colon, that colon at the end displays lower than all of the other characters, including any other colons in the text. Is this normal, expected behavior in SwiftUI? Is there any way to prohibit this from happening?
Input:
let myText: String = "1:2:3:".trimmingCharacters(in: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
var body: some View {
    Text("8:8:8:")
    Text("8:8:8:8")
    Text(myText)
}

Output:


I wonder if you can use a replace to test the string for the empty, and then replace it with the old alt-255 invisible space ASCII ?  8:8:8:                 <-- this

I am very new to Swift and SwiftUI. I'm not sure what empty means in this context, as both strings were not empty. Please forgive my ignorance.

I don't use it all, I was refering to the concept of a data type ,  an Empty value or in string terms variable = "" sort of thing.  I wonder if you can use a REGEX statement to test the string to see if it is missing the last value, and then replace the empty space with this -->      <--  it looks like a space but its ascii so it might just work to make it fix that issue.  It doesn't fix the reason it happens but it could repair it.

Could there possibly be something empty or hidden when I literally typed in Text("8:8:8:")

Ow wow, it's lower in the comment too when I copy and paste it from above. I'm sure you're on the right track and I'm just being dense but I don't know how to test it when it was just literally typed out even and not stored in a String.

Oh okay, so that space must be in it.  If you hold ALT and press 255 you will generate the ASCII space I'm talking about.  Or perhaps its another character but that is strange.

This article
provides some explanations regarding String Interpolation in SwiftUI.
"SwiftUI interprets the colon as a special character, indicating that the following text should be formatted as a LocalizedStringKey"

This is a font-feature called "vertically centered colon." It is automatically applied between digits. Otherwise, it is not applied by default. Your tests only involve digits; if you used letters you would see different results.
Not all fonts have this feature, but San Francisco (which is the default here) does. For example, adding .fontDesign(.monospaced) will get rid of this, as will .font(.custom("Helvetica", size: 18)).
There is no nice way I know of to modify the features of a SwiftUI Font. You can do it using techniques similar to UIFont: How to use Stylistic Alternate character?:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("8:8:8:")
            .font(thefont())
    }
}

func thefont() -> Font {
    let baseFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    let descriptor = CTFontDescriptorCreateCopyWithFeature(
        baseFont.fontDescriptor,
        kStylisticAlternativesType as CFNumber,
        6 as CFNumber)
    return Font(UIFont(descriptor: descriptor, size: 0.0))
}

This will enable centered-colon for the entire string. It's a pretty ugly solution, but I don't know of any more SwiftUI-friendly approach.

Note regarding "...if you used letters you would see different results". In my tests, Text("A:B:C:")
give you the same lower last colon, but not Text("a:b:c:")

Thank you so much, this solved it for me, and it makes perfect sense.
